# Using Regular Expression in R

Tags: r

Hi I am trying to extract a single sentence from a paragraph in R

```
"[report_beginning]

101962493|2011-06-09|final|Omary, Lea, M.D.|43654754|Major Academic Center

_Ms.Wattley is a 88 year-old patient who comes in today with a chief complaint of PREG/SPOTTING.

ALLERGIES: Â none

SOCIAL HISTORY: Â The patient Ms.Wattley is a past smoker who has a visiting nurse. Patient is bed-bound.

PHYSICAL EXAMINATION: Â Blood pressure 125/98, pulse 55, respiratory rate 7, temperature 98.7, and O2 saturation 98 on room air. Â General: Â This is a patient in severe distress. Â 

 EMERGENCY DEPARTMENT COURSE: Â I confirm that I have seen and evaluated the patient, reviewed the resident's documentation on the patient's chart. The following procedures were performed: Medication:medication given. Procedure:no procedures performed. Testing:testing conducted . Please review the chart for more details.

 DISPOSITION: Â The patient was admitted to the hospital with a primary diagnosis of Threatened abortion, antepartum condition or complication.
```

And so this is one cell. I have a column full of data like this and I want to extract a single line. "PHYSICAL EXAMINATION: Â Blood pressure 125/98, pulse 55, respiratory rate 7, temperature 98.7, and O2 saturation 98 on room air."

How can I do this with Regular expression in R?

I have been using the following code but it doesn't work. It gives me an empty dataset

```
x=grep("Blood pressure .+ air. ", ed_dia, value = TRUE)
```

Comment: If you know the complete sentence beforehand why do you need to extract it?

Comment: Because this sentence repeats itself throughout the dataset @nrussell

Comment: Please include a sample of your data set and the desired output. Your question is not clear as is.

Comment: I would kind of like to see the title changed.  In the future I can imagine that anytime someone types 'regular expressions R' into a search engine this post will be the first hit.

Comment: Hi @MarkMiller. Thanks I have changed the post title

Comment: The edit you made (to remove the title and body of your post) is generally discouraged on SO. Please consider at least using a sensible title even if you think it appropriate to cut out most of the body. @MarkMiller If you have a better idea for a title, maybe you could suggest it.

Comment: Also note that you made the post more visible by editing it and putting it on the front page :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `"[report begiinning` is not actually in the data file, so opening a text connection to read the file should succeed:

```
txt <- "101962493|2011-06-09|final|Omary, Lea, M.D.|43654754|Major Academic Center

_Ms.Wattley is a 88 year-old patient who comes in today with a chief complaint of PREG/SPOTTING.

ALLERGIES: Â none

SOCIAL HISTORY: Â The patient Ms.Wattley is a past smoker who has a visiting nurse. Patient is bed-bound.

PHYSICAL EXAMINATION: Â Blood pressure 125/98, pulse 55, respiratory rate 7, temperature 98.7, and O2 saturation 98 on room air. Â General: Â This is a patient in severe distress. Â 

 EMERGENCY DEPARTMENT COURSE: Â I confirm that I have seen and evaluated the patient, reviewed the resident's documentation on the patient's chart. The following procedures were performed: Medication:medication given. Procedure:no procedures performed. Testing:testing conducted . Please review the chart for more details.

 DISPOSITION: Â The patient was admitted to the hospital with a primary diagnosis of Threatened abortion, antepartum condition or complication. "

inp <- readLines( textConnection(txt))
```

So after data input it only remains to use `grep` to identify the lines with `"PHYSICAL EXAMINATION"` (I wasn't sure if the space may needed special regex-handling) in them and then use `"["` to extract from the multiple lines:

```
inp[ grep("PHYSICAL[ ]EXAMINATION", inp)]
#[1] "PHYSICAL EXAMINATION: Â Blood pressure 125/98, pulse 55, respiratory rate 7, temperature 98.7, and O2 saturation 98 on room air. Â General: Â This is a patient in severe distress. Â "
```